# Gland defined based on morphology or hormone secretion?

Tags: endocrinology, histology

Is a gland defined by a visible morphology, or is anything that secretes a hormone a gland?

The answer does matter for the definition of histamine. Based on the answer I can conclude whether it's an hormone or not.

Comment: Glands can be classified as endocrines or exocrines, and only endocrine glands secrete hormones. Thus, not all glands secrete hormones. Regarding your second paragraph (*"The answer does matter for the definition of histamine. Based on the answer I can conclude whether it's an hormone or not."*) I have absolutely no idea at all of what you tried to say here.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. Maybe I didn't explain myself well, so it would be better to see the place that the question came from... (kindly, look at "Wnt" things) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Science#Histamine_is_considered_as_hormone_or_not.3F

Comment: Now I understand your question. You could actually go directly to the point, asking this in the title: *"Is histamine an hormone or not?"*.